# Flutter api post request error with golang api working with in postman but not flutter

Tags: flutter, api, go, error-handling, postman

```
src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
I/flutter (10634):  </body>
I/flutter (10634): </html>
```

*My problem is in making a post request to my golang api it is working fine in postman but not in flutter it giving some error like this could anyone help me with this*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Flutter throws Handsake errors like CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED etc.
Maybe you should try to override the default HttpOverrides class.

```html
/// Override the badCertificateCallback to always true.
class NewHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

...

/// Change the global HttpOverrides before runApp.
void main(){
  HttpOverrides.global = NewHttpOverrides();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```